# How do I filter AWS Cloud Watch Logs on a hash on the main page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How can I go directly to the log 7cf2c033bfec48e8a74c40b08cdxx15f from the main Cloud Watch logs page filter? This is the one that filters out log groups.

Here is the message

```
Failed to create resource. See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2019/08/22/[$LATEST]7cf2c033bfec48e8a74c40b08cdxx15f
```

Now I want to use the hash to find the log group and the log stream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with Logs Insights.

1. On CloudWatch Console, navigate to Insights on the left panel (just under logs).
2. Click the *Select log group(s)* on the top and select all of them.
3. Select the correct time range for the log stream. You can see it in the log stream name, `2019/08/22/[$LATEST]...`
4. Use this query: `fields @log, @logStream, @message | filter @logStream like "7cf2c033bfec48e8a74c40b08cdxx15f"`

Description of fields:

- **@log** will give you the log group
- **@logStream** will give you the stream name and it should be a clickable link to the actual stream.
- **@message** will give you the log line.