# Any way to search across all log streams in a cloud watch log group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In AWS console, I can search for a string in all log streams of a log group? Right now, I have to go inside each log stream and then do search which takes a lot of time, if I want to search across the log streams.

Comment: Similar problem, answer there might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617203/how-do-i-filter-aws-cloud-watch-logs-on-a-hash-on-the-main-page/57625466#57625466

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Once you click the log group in the CloudWatch Logs console, but before you click into an individual log stream, there is a button at the top right of the page labeled "Search Log Group". Click that, and it will take you to a page where you can search across all logs in the log group in a given time frame.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to limit this result to log streams that match a particular pattern?

Answer (score 12):

What you need is the CloudWacth Log Insight.

It cost some money to do data scanning this way though

[image]